# Error: sudo: a password is required\r\n - although user have permissions on sudoers

Tags: linux, permissions, ansible, couchbase

I am trying to run a simple Ansible playbook that shows a content of 'home' directory.

It runs successfully, but when I use:

```
become_user: "{{ TARGET_USER }}"
```

I get error:

```
 "sudo: a password is required\r\n"
```

The 'Ansible user' is "blnapp1" and the 'Target user' is "couchbase"

I added permissions for "blnapp1" and "couchbase" users inside sudoers file as follows:

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL 
blnapp1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
blnapp1 ALL=(ALL) ALL
ansible ALL= NOPASSWD: /home/blnapp1/playbook #path to playbook
couchbase ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
couchbase ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I also added to all of the users ssh public key of each other into /.ssh/authorized_keys

Here is my inventory file:

```
web1 ansible_host=**** ansible_connection=local

[couchbase-install:children]
couchbase_cluster_nodes
couchbase_server_nodes

[couchbase_cluster_nodes]
primary1 ansible_host=**** ansible_user=blnapp1 TARGET_USER=couchbase couchbase_primary_cluster_node=**** couchbase_cluster_admin_port=*** couchbase_bucket_name=exampleBucket group_server=default

[couchbase_server_nodes]

[all:vars]
#configuration_mode can be vars or cc
configuration_mode=vars
couchbase_data_path="/userdata/data/CB/var/lib/couchbase/data"
couchbase_index_path= "/userdata/data/CB/var/lib/couchbase/data"
yum_path="sudo /bin/yum"
#couchbase_admin="Administrator"
#couchbase_password="Administrator"
```

And here is my playbook:

```
---

- name: I-test
  hosts: primary1
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ TARGET_USER }}"

  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: 'TARGET_USER is: "{{ TARGET_USER }}"'
  - name: show repo content
    shell: 
      cmd: ls -la /home
```

The only way I found is to add "blnapp1" user to 'wheel' group. However, I really don't want "blnapp1" to have 'wheel' permissions..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
blnapp1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
blnapp1 ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Those 2 lines basically tell the exact same thing: let `blnapp1` launch any command as anyone. But the first one tells `sudo` not to ask for a password while the second one doesn't.

And after testing quickly against a `debian:buster` docker image, it appears only the last line encountered rules in this case, making `sudo` always ask for a password.

Simply remove the second line in your sudoers file. Note that you have the exact same problem for your `couchbase` user.

Comment: Thank for the advice. I tried what you said, however still getting the same error..

Comment: Did you edit the file with `visudo` ? Else sudo might not have catched the changes...

Comment: Yes of course, edited with     visudo and made sure the changes are there.

Comment: Can you try with: `blnapp1 ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` ?